# placeholder text and typed in text not aligning in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextfield with some placeholder text.

I have used both alignment properties. However, the palceholder text is still a little on the upper side. Can anyone help me out ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the actual code that you are using?

Comment: I ended up subclassing UITextField and overriding drawPlaceholderInRect and drawTextInRect. I noticed three distinct pieces -- the drawn static text, the editing text, and the placeholder. I think the way the editing mode was set up takes into account some issues with the font itself in a way that doesn't affect the static text. But the static was the easiest to override to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution in MonoTouch for having to fix the alignment of placeholder vs text. As I noted in the comments -- there are three distinct pieces: the editing, the static text, and the static placeholder. The equivalent in Objective-C is **drawTextInRect:** and **drawPlaceholderInRect:**.

My solution was to subclass and offset the mis-aligned items. Unfortunately the issue seems to be related to the font-file itself and how editing mode affects it, vs. how iOS renders static text.

Hope this helps someone.

Allison

```
public class MyTextField : UITextField
{
    public MyTextField(RectangleF rect) : base(rect)
    {
    }

    public override void DrawPlaceholder(RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.DrawPlaceholder(new RectangleF(rect.X, rect.Y + 2, rect.Width, rect.Height));
    }

    public override void DrawText(RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.DrawText(new RectangleF(rect.X, rect.Y + 2, rect.Width, rect.Height));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `UITextField` documentation you should be using the `textAlignment` property. As  the docs state "This property applies to the both the main text string and the placeholder string. The default value of this property is UITextAlignmentLeft."

So your code would look something like:

```
textfield.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft
```

or depending on how you want to align the text you could use `UITextAlignmentCenter` or `UITextAlignmentRight` after the `=` sign.

Comment: Well, this doesnt help. Its like either the typed in text is aligned or the placeholder text is aligned (center vertical alignment). Not sure why these two texts are not both aligned properly

Answer (score 0):

I'd say play around with the Y Size of you used CGRectMake to create your frame. Maybe make it smaller?